# random number generator test

Tags: algorithm, unit-testing, testing

How will you test if the random number generator is generating actual random numbers?

My Approach: Firstly build a hash of size M, where M is the prime number. Then take the number
             generated by random number generator, and take mod with M.
             and see it fills in all the hash or just in some part.
             That's my approach. Can we prove it with visualization?

Since I have very less knowledge about testing. Can you suggest me a thorough approach of this question? Thanks in advance

Comment: Many very bad random number generators could pass that test. For example, one that just returned a number one greater than the previous each time would pass. You need a battery of tests, like [diehard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diehard_tests). Note that the tests need to be run a number of times and the number of failures must be in the expected range.

Comment: Since I am new in testing, I have one more approach, just take a @-d matrix, and make a loop of 100,000 times and fills that matrix with color and observe that matrix. Is t good or not?

Comment: What means the number of failure here?
Please explain me.

Comment: The matrix would be a very, very weak test. (Because you wouldn't know how far off it was supposed to be and couldn't numerically quantify the results.) The number of failures is the number of times the random number generator failed the test. If you test at the 99% confidence interval, you should fail about one of 100 tests. (Just as a fair coin will sometimes just happen to give more heads than tails.)

Comment: Say you flip a coin 100 times and get 43 heads. Did the coin pass the randomness test? Well, if you let 43 heads pass, a really lousy coin can pass your test almost all of the time. But if you make 43 heads fail, then fair coins will sometimes (though not often) fail your test. So if you want to use a strong test, you need to look at the *number* of failures and see if it's reasonable.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Yes and no. The matrix is the way to go, it is how common statistical tests work. The clever part is doing the post processing and determining how exactly we *use* this matrix. Of course a perfect uniform distribution is unlikely - but what is? This is what statistical tests do. I added an example for such a test (Pearson's chi-square) as an answer.

Comment: Go and look at Knuth 'The Art of Programming: Volume 2: Semi-numerical Algorithms'.  Chapter 3 is about Random Numbers, and includes lots of information about how to test random number generators.  See also [Dilbert's Tour of Accounting](http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2001-10-25/).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be aware that you cannot *guarantee* the random number generator is working properly. Note that even a perfect uniform distribution in range [1,10] - there is a 10<sup>-10</sup> chance of getting 10 times 10 in a random sampling of 10 numbers.

Is it likely? Of course not.

So - what *can* we do?

We can **statistically prove** that the combination (10,10,....,10) is *unlikely* if the random number generator is indeed uniformly distributed. This concept is called **[Hypothesis testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing)**. With this approach we can say "with certainty level of x% - we can reject the hypothesis that the data is taken from a uniform distribution".

A common way to do it, is using **[Pearson's Chi-Squared test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test)**, The idea is similar to yours - you fill in a table - check what is the *observed* (generated) number of numbers for each cell, and what is the *expected* number of numbers for each cell under the null hypothesis (in your case, the expected is `k/M` - where M is the range's size, and k is the total number of numbers taken).

You then do some manipulation on the data (see the wikipedia article for more info what this manipulation is exactly) - and get a number (the test statistic). You then check if this number is *likely* to be taken from a [Chi-Square Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution). If it is - you cannot reject the null hypothesis, if it is not - you can be certain with x% certainty that the data is not taken from a uniform random generator.

**EDIT:** example:

You have a cube, and you want to check if it is "fair" (uniformly distributed in `[1,6]`). Throw it 200 times (for example) and create the following table:

```
number:                1       2         3         4          5          6
empirical occurances: 37       41        30        27         32         33
expected occurances: 33.3      33.3      33.3      33.3       33.3       33.3
```

Now, according to Pearson's test, the statistic is:

```
X = ((37-33.3)^2)/33.3 + ((41-33.3)^2)/33.3 + ... + ((33-33.3)^2)/33.3 
X = (18.49 + 59.29 + 10.89 + 39.69 + 1.69 + 0.09) / 33.3
X = 3.9
```

For a random `C~ChiSquare(5)`, the probability of being higher then `3.9` is `~0.45` (which is not improbable)<sup>1</sup>.

So we *cannot* reject the null hypothesis, and we can conclude that the data is *probably* uniformly distributed in `[1,6]`

---

(1) We usually reject the null hypothesis if the value is smaller then 0.05, but this is very case dependent.

Comment: amit, tell me one thing, first you calculate x = 3.9
but, after that the steps you wrote is beyond my understanding, can you explain this again, elaborately...plz

Comment: @jhamb: We first find `X` (the test statistic), and then - in order to calculate the [P-Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value) (which is the lowest probability we can reject the null hypothesis) - we need to find `P(C>X)` where C~ChiSquared(5) (The probability of getting a result at least as extreme as X from the ChiSquared distribution with 5 degrees freedom). To find what is `P(C>X)` we can use a statistic table or a program like excel (We cannot calculate this probability directly).

Comment: tell me one more thing, how you got `0.45`?\

Comment: It is a mistake I am afraid, the real value is probably 0.55-0.6. You go to a chi-aquare distribution table, similar to [this one](http://www.sixsigmadigest.com/store/image/cache/data/chi-sq-dist-500x500.png), and you find under 5 degrees freedom the value that is closest to the value you have. In our case it is somewhere in the interval [0.5,0.75], which is high. so the outcome we got is not unexpected, and we cannot reject the fairness hypothesis. (We usually do if we get 0.05 or lower)

Comment: are there any tools can do this for us with a large input of RN?

Answer (score 1):

My naive idea:
The generator is following a distribution. (At least it should.) Do a reasonable amount of runs then plot the values on a graph. Fit a regression curve on the points. If it correlates with the shape of the distribution you're good. (This is also possible in 1D with projections and histograms. And fully automatable with the correct tool, e.g. MatLab) 
You can also use the diehard tests as it was mentioned before, that is surely better but involves much less intuition, at least on your side.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to generate a uniform distribution on the interval [0, 1].

Then one possible test is

```
for i from 1 to sample-size
when a < random-being-tested() < b
counter +1
return counter/sample-size
```

And see if the result is closed to b-a (b minus a).

Of course you should define a function taking a, b between 0 and 1 as inputs, and return the difference between the counter/sample-size and b-a. Loop through possible a, b, say of the multiples of 0.01, a < b. Print out a, b when the difference is larger than a preset epsilon, say 0.001.

Those are the a, b for which there are too many outliers.

If you let sample-size be 5000. Your random-being-tested will be called about 5000 * 5050 times in total, hopefully not too bad.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
when I finish to write my code (using an external RNG engine)

I looked on the results and found that all of them fail Chi-Square test whenever I have to many results.

my code generated a random number and hold buckets of the amount of each result range.
I don't know why the Chi-square test fail when i have a lot of results.

during my research I saw that the C# Random.next() fail in any range of random and that some of the numbers have better odds than the other, further more i saw that the RNGCryptoServiceProvider random provider is not supporting good on big numbers.

when trying to get numbers in the range of 0-1,000,000,000 the numbers in the lower range 0-300M have better odds to appear...

as a result I'm using the RNGCryptoServiceProvider and if my range is higher than 100M i'm combine the number my self (RandomHigh*100M + RandomLow) and the ranges of both randoms is smaller than 100M so it good.

Good Luck!

Comment: Whoa, slow down there. You might want to go back over this and make it  more readable; one long paragraph usually isn't the way to go.