# Java Unique Number Generator collision test runs out of memory

Tags: java, algorithm, testing, random

I have a system requirement to generate an 11 characters string where 8 rightmost characters must be unique.

Now from my understanding, at most this happens few hundreds of times per day.
Due to speed concerns, I was asked to avoid using a DB to simply retrieve the nextval() in a sequence unfortunately.

So I am left to test various ways to generate a random number as good as possible, and I've come up with a solution based on SecureRandom class.

I decided to test it, to see how likely it is that a generated string would repeat itself; I tested using a HashMap (string, string) for 10 million generations - looks good, and was hoping to test for the night for  billion random strings, but that has failed due to Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

The test code I have so far is this:

```
public class Main {
public static BigInteger BASE = BigInteger.valueOf(62);
public static final String DIGITS = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    long lStartTime = System.nanoTime();
    HashMap<String, String> orders = new HashMap<String, String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 960000000; i++) {
        SecureRandom randObj = new SecureRandom();
        BigInteger BigRand = new BigInteger(128, randObj);
        String rand = BigRand.toString(62);

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        while (BigRand.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 1 && result.length()<11) { // number > 0
              BigInteger[] divmod = BigRand.divideAndRemainder(BASE);
              BigRand = divmod[0];
              int digit = divmod[1].intValue();
              result.insert(0, DIGITS.charAt(digit));
            }
        String doesKeyExistString = orders.get(result);
        if (doesKeyExistString != null) {
            System.out.print("Duplicate key found!: "+result.toString()+"\n");
        } else {
            orders.put(result.toString(), result.toString());  // No such key
        }
    }
    long lEndTime = System.nanoTime();
    long difference1 = lEndTime - lStartTime;
    double difference = (double)difference1/1000000000;
    System.out.println("Elapsed seconds: " + difference);
    System.out.println("Elapsed exact: " + difference1);

}
```

Do you have any suggestions how to prove that we can rely on this method of generating random numbers, with likelyhood of getting the same string twice small enough?

I stumbled across this question: [random number generator test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190091/random-number-generator-test)
The answer looks interesting, but I didn't quite understand how to apply this to my case (Statistics was my hardest course, I barely passed it the second attempt...)

I am also not sure, how to adjust this random generator to dynamically set the length of the generated number.. there have to be better ways to do this than what I did here...

Thanks!

Comment: A billion times 11 characters times 2 bytes is 22GB without considering object or hashtable overhead. Can you really afford that just for this trivial function? Do you *have* it? And how can there possibly be any speed concerns about something that only happens a few hundred times a day? Somebody is wasting your time.

Comment: How many unique 11-char you need per unit of time? Because reversed unixtime might be a good generator in your case

Comment: If you have disk space, you could use a database to store the generated elementd (for your test)

Comment: @EJP I only run this to test the likelihood of a repeated identical string in 1 billion attempts. In production I will only do one, but I want to know that the likelihood is really negligible.

Comment: @RC. - Your idea of using unix time is very interesting! I just have to mitigate the risk of 2 transactions hitting the service at the same second.. not sure how though. And you are right.. I suppose I could try writing to DB just for the local test.

Comment: A lock and some temporisation might help ensure you don't have 2 transaction at the same time. In fact I would use a custom unixtime (1/10th precision, so 11 char) reversed, a lock and a "sleep" of 1 second

Comment: The likelihood of a repeated string over a billion iterations is (of the order of) 1/1000000000, unless there is something seriously wrong with your random number generator. It is now impossible to determine what you are actually asking here.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take a look at the raw numbers here.

You're trying to store one billion 11 character long strings in a `HashMap`.

If we calculate the absolutely minimum space for this (11 character array + int for length) that gives us:

```
1e9 * (11 * 2 bytes + 4 bytes) = 26e9 bytes
```

or about 24 gigabytes. That is how much memory your solution requires.

If we look at the other side of the equation. You're looking to randomly generate two equal strings of length 8 using a 62 character alphabet. That means you have

```
62 ^ 8 = 218340105584896
```

or about `2.18e14` different combinations. Looking at the [birthday problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#The_generalized_birthday_problem) we can calculate the number of strings we need to generate to have a probability of at least 50% to have generated the same string twice. Following the formula, that number is about `1.74e7` times. So if you generate 18 million strings the probability that you have generated the same string twice is more than 50%.

18 million strings should only require

```
1.8e7 * (11 * 2 bytes + 4 bytes) = 4.68e8 bytes
```

or about 470 megabytes, which should be within your limitations.

Now, as for your actual problem - use a [random UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29) if possible since you can rely on the possibility of generating the same UUID twice is, for all practical purposes, nonexistant.

If you can't use an UUID but have to use those 8 characters I suggest you expand your alphabet a bit. By using all printable ASCII characters (95 characters) you increase the number of possible combinations to slightly less than 6.1e15 - though the number of generations for a 50% chance of a collision only increases to around 90 million.

Comment: Thanks Raniz, problem is that UUID is much more than my 11 characters limitation.

Comment: Then your only option is to get as much entropy as you can from those 11 (or 8) characters. Increase the alphabet size. If you can use a multi-byte encoding you can throw a few extra characters in there until you get to a satisfactory number of total possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using UUID ([Universally Unique Identifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html)) in JAVA.

```
UUID idOne = UUID.randomUUID();
System.out.println( idOne.toString() );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer attempt but.. have you read that I specified the number should be not longer than 11 characters? with the rightmost 8 unique? So at most I can do 11 characters unique number.. That is why I discarded the possibility of utilizing a UUID...

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered *sequential* numbers? Starting from 000000000? Then you only have to remember the last number you allocated.

It's hard to get excited about this as a performance problem when it only happens a few hundred times a day. That's only 41 *per hour* at 24 hours times 999 operations.

Comment: I have considered it for few days now.
How do you ensure sequential, if you cant use a DB? One thought that was raised is to use a file to keep a counter, but then there is a concurrency issue and redundancy in case of switching to backup server (although on same machine/disk, as I understand it).

I was thinking of a compromise using SQLite file DB, but I am told this solution is also prone to file/DB corruption, with higher likelihood than a SecureRandom generated number (or other random number)

Comment: I've answered that. Remember the last number you allocated. You don't need a DB for that. In terms of the newly introduced issue of backup servers, which wasn't present in your original question, you can't ensure *anything* if you can't use a DB. And *why* can't you use a DB? The constraint is in my considered opinion quite ridiculous. What you have been told is very low quality. A sequential scheme is considerably more reliable than a scheme that you can't even implement because it needs a 22Gb, *persistent,* hash table.

Comment: I only need the 22Gb during probability testing, nothing more... And the reason for no DB constraint is business reason - there are limitations on the time the transaction is allowed to take, so they hinted (told) me a couple of times that preferred solution should not add a DB to the complexity...

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an 'out of memory' error because you're running out of memory.

The text says you're running 10 million trials but the code is trying to run 960 million (`for (int i = 0; i < 960000000; i++) {`).

Reduce the size of that loop or increase the memory available to the program (e.g. using the java command-line).

If you can't allocate the memory and really need such a massive trial attach a database table or other external storage.