# Using javascript to A/B test landing pages, Math.random() not random?

Tags: javascript, random, google-analytics

I have a javascript ad that runs on multiple websites. The ad is for an app, and when clicking the ad the user is sent to a landing page where js on that landing page determines whether to show A) landing page A, B) landing page B) or C) redirect the user to app store/play store.

The ad is choosing landing pages dynamically, by setting the parameter utm_content={landingA, landingB, nolanding}, so there are basically three choices:

- Directly to store (50%)
- Landing page (50%)

  - Landing A (50%)
  - Landing B (50%)

The way this is chosen is by pure js and the code is like this:

```
if(Math.random() < 0.5) nolanding;
else {
 if (Math.random() < 0.5) landingA;
 else landingB; 
}
```

When the user then clicks the ad, he or she is sent to the landing page, and based on the utm_content parameter's value, the landing page is showing A / B or redirect to store without showing anything.

In Google Analytics I made a pie chart to just test if the traffic is distributed 50%, 25%, 25%, but that does not seem to be the case.

[image]

As you ca see from the attached image, it does not have the expected distribution.
So, my question is:

Is the problem that the Math.random() is not as random as I expect? I've looked into some other questions discussing that issue, but it cannot be that inaccurate?

Or is it Google Analytics not being able to track the utm_content parameter correctly? Could it be an issue with the redirect to stores going too fast, so GA can't track the page view?

EDIT: Here is the pie chart setup:

It will only show data that also has the utm_campaign= dynamiskNA or dynamiskTF which is exactly what I want to see.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062902/how-random-is-javascripts-math-random

Comment: It's more likely that the pie chart doesn't count the things you want it to count (Does it include the initial landing page? Traffic from other sources?)

Comment: @hindmost Yep, I actually believe that it is GA that causes the problem.

Juhana: See the pie chart setup in my edit.

Comment: required reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190091/random-number-generator-test

Comment: @Paul Yep, I've read it now. I get that there is a probability that the numbers won't be exactly 50/25/25, but in my case the pie chart is more like 25/34/41, and the weird thing is that it 'nolanding' which is expected to have 50% of the traffic has less than 25%...

Comment: @stianlp It doesn't worry me.  But that chi square test can determine roughly how odd it is.  I'm a bit sleepy to try it.  If you need help with the chi square test, you could try it and see how far you get and ask followup questions about the math/stats on http://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Paul Yep calculated it, and I am not even in the table. Remember that the blue are is supposed to be 25% and the red area is supposed to be 50%. T

EDIT: Used this example http://www2.lv.psu.edu/jxm57/irp/chisquar.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem was with the ga('send' 'pageview') event. I did not wait for the hitCallback from GA before redirecting, and therefore GA did not track all events.

It's a pretty straightforward solution, and a stupid mistake.

BEFORE:

```
ga('send' 'pageview');
// Went ahead and redirected
```

AFTER:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {'hitCallback' : function() {
    //Go ahead an do stuff :)
}});
```

@Paul Thanks for showing me the chi square test. Learned something useful :)